# Session makes the variable update data twice

Tags: angularjs, node.js, session

Every time I get a new price, the following is supposed to happen:
**totalprice = totalprice + cart[i]**
For example, if the **totalprice** was previously 500 and a new price is 800, the **totalprice** is supposed to be (500 + 800) whereas it's currently (500 + 500 + 800). Why does this happen?

```
exports.add = function(req, res) {
    var cart = req.body.cart;
    console.log('frome node..adding checkcart.js');
    console.log("Session Initialized!!");
    for(var i = 0 ; i < cart.length ; i++) {
        totalprice = cart[i].price + totalprice;
        console.log('Current Price: '+cart[i].price);
    }
    req.session.cart = cart;
    console.log(cart);
    console.log('total: ' + totalprice);
    //req.session.totalprice = totalprice;
    json_responses = {
        "totalprice": req.session.totalprice
    }
    res.send(json_responses);
};
```

Comment: Add the console logs as an example

Comment: frome node..adding checkcart.js
[ { uid: 'lenvyga', product: 'Lenovo Yoga', price: 800 } ]
Session Initialized!!
Current Price: 800
total: 800
POST /addtocart 200 117.127 ms - 2
frome node..adding checkcart.js
[ { uid: 'lenvyga', product: 'Lenovo Yoga', price: 800 },
  { uid: 'macbpr', product: 'MacBook Pro', price: 1200 } ]
Session Initialized!!
Current Price: 800
Current Price: 1200
total: 2800

Comment: Where is the problem?

First, the total price is 0, when added 800 it changes to 800 as mentioned in the console log. Then you add two more, (1) 800 and (2) 1200. So it takes the totalprice (currently 800) and adds price (1) and (2). Which makes it 800+1200+800 which is supposed to be 2800. That is, exactly what you get (according to the console log).

Comment: the thing is I am pushing the items into an array and thus I am not pushing two items 2nd time, but only one. But it takes values for both.

Comment: Hey jack, if the answer below solved your problem mark it with the green V (checkmark) to notify other users reading this question of the correct answer. If it didn't please let me know why.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of many answers. I would suggest creating a variable that will count the amount of items already added. Otherwise, your for loop will keep counting them all again and again. Bare in mind your question lacks a lot of code, so this will have me add two options.

**Option 1**

Every time a user adds an item the add function will be called. For this option all you have to do is add the **last** added item to the total price calculation. So in your code, instead of:

```
for(var i = 0 ; i < cart.length ; i++) {
    totalprice = cart[i].price + totalprice;
    console.log('Current Price: '+cart[i].price);
}
```

Use:

```
totalprice = cart[cart.length-1].price + totalprice;
```

**Option 2**

This option is for when a user can add many items, and the prices are calculated once the user clicks a button that calls the add method. This is just slightly more tricky. You need to add a counter that will count the items already calculated. So in code:

```
var counter = 0;
exports.add = function(req, res) {
    var cart = req.body.cart;
    var prevCounter = counter;
    counter = req.body.cart.length - counter; // items added in the session
    console.log('frome node..adding checkcart.js');
    console.log("Session Initialized!!");
    for(var i = prevCounter ; i < counter ; i++) {
        totalprice = cart[i].price + totalprice;
        console.log('Current Price: ' + cart[i].price);
    }
    req.session.cart = cart;
    console.log(cart);
    console.log('total: ' + totalprice);
    //req.session.totalprice = totalprice;
    json_responses = {
        "totalprice": req.session.totalprice
    }
    res.send(json_responses);
};
```

Good luck !